# Magento 2 - admin order grid, date filter not filtering correct orders

Tags: magento2

I have **Magento 2.2.7** version installed and store timezone is set to **India Standard Time (+05:30)**. Magento internally save order date and time in *UTC* and hence order placed date and time (India Standard Time) from store is different than what is saved in database table.

When I filter orders in admin by *Purchase Date*, it list orders filtered by UTC time not in the Indian Time. This doesn't show orders placed between 00:01 am to 05:30 am.

Is there any configuration in admin for this?

Note : I already search for this on google but didn't get any perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is configured at the admin user account level. Be warned, last time I tried setting an admin user to a none en_US locale setting it broke magento for them.